# Why can‘t I run riscv64 elf(compiled on host) in qemu-system-riscv64?

Tags: qemu, riscv, busybox, rootfs

I compiled a `#include<stdio.h> int main() { printf("hello world\n"); return 0; }` program with `riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc ./test.c -o test` on my x86_64-Ubuntu22.04 host, then I put this executable into the shared folder mnt. When I execute `./test` I just get `-/bin/sh: ./test: not found` from terminal. Isn't it just a piece of binary code without shared lib?

My options of qemu startup are `qemu-system-riscv64 -nographic -m 256M -machine virt -kernel ~/linux-kernel/arch/riscv/boot/Image -append \"root=/dev/vda rw console=ttyS0\" -drive file=rootfs.img,format=raw,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -fsdev local,security_model=passthrough,id=fsdev0,path=./host_mnt -device virtio-9p pci,id=fs0,fsdev=fsdev0,mount_tag=hostshare`. And I create my `ext4 rootfs` just with `dd and busybox`. Here are the basic commands I used.

```
$ qemu-img create rootfs.img  8g
$ mkfs.ext4 rootfs.img
$ mkdir rootfs
$ sudo mount -o loop rootfs.img  rootfs
$ cd rootfs
$ sudo cp -r ../busyboxsource/_install/* .
$ sudo mkdir proc sys dev etc etc/init.d
$ cd etc/init.d/
$ sudo touch rcS
$ sudo vi rcS
    #!/bin/sh
    mount -t proc none /proc
    mount -t sysfs none /sys
    /sbin/mdev -s
    mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L hostshare /mnt
$ sudo chmod +x rcS
$ sudo umount rootfs
(creating rootfs finished)
```

And the versions of riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc, QEMU and linux kernel(in qemu) are:

`riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (g2ee5e430018) 12.2.0`
`QEMU emulator version 8.0.0 (v8.0.0)`
`v6.0.0`

I am confused why the elf compiled on host can not be executed inside qemu. Is it because my `rootfs` is created with `busybox` and not based on, say, `ubuntu rootfs`, or something else? I can offer more information about my environment if needed. I'd appreciate it if anyone can explain this for me.

Thanks!

I tried `ldd test` on host and got `not a dynamic executable`.

I will try to build rootfs based on ubuntu if this is the reason.

Comment: gcc usually creates dynamically linked executables by default.  What happens if you compile with `-static`?  I'm not sure that the `ldd` output of "not a dynamic executable" is meaningful, since that is the ldd for a different architecture.

Comment: You also made sure that you preserved the execute permissions on `test`?  Check with `ls -l test` inside the guest.

Comment: Yes! I just got home and turned on my computer to try `-static` option(I saw it from somewhere before but overlooked it). And it indeed works. But is it a good and lasting solution? If not, what should I do? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Indeed building the root filesystem based on debian/ubuntu will be better.